# Filtering and restricting in query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I would like to seek some help in my query...i want to do is if specific `atic` and `oaic` is empty in the table...the `interview_sum` or `other_sum` to that specific `atic` `oaic` should be empty too....can anyone know how to do that?

picture of current output:[image]

current query: my query still gives numbers to other_sum or interview_sum even its empty.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
IF(t.inttotal=NULL,0,(SELECT SUM(t2.inttotal)
 FROM app_interview2 AS t2 
 WHERE t2.atic = t.atic AND t2.inttotal>0)/7)
 AS interview_sum,

IF(o.ototal=NULL,0,(SELECT SUM(o2.ototal)
 FROM other_app2 AS o2 
 WHERE o2.oaic = o.oaic AND o2.ototal>0)/7)
 AS other_sum,

atid,
atic,
atname,
region,
town,
uniq_id,
position,
salary_grade,
salary
FROM app_interview2 AS t, other_app2 AS o
GROUP BY t.atname HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t.atic)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a few assumptions:

- You probably have a table that app_interview2.atic and other_app2.oaic are the foreign keys of, but since you did not share it, I derived a table in the `FROM` clause.
- This assumes atname is always the same for atid.
- You are also dividing by 7 - which I assume is to get the average, so I used the AVG function.

Solution---

```
SELECT t1.id AS atid
       ,interview.atname AS atname
       ,COALESCE(interview.interviewsum, 0) AS interviewsum
       ,COALESCE(interview.interviewavg,0) AS interviewavg 
       ,COALESCE(other.othersum, 0) AS othersum
       ,COALESCE(other.otheravg) AS otheravg
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT atid AS id
      FROM app_interview2
      UNION
      SELECT DISTINCT oaic 
      FROM other_app2) AS t1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT atid, atname, SUM(inttotal) AS interviewsum, AVG(inttotal) AS interviewavg
           FROM app_interview2
           GROUP BY atid, atname) as interview
  ON interview.atid = t1.id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT oaic, SUM(ototal) AS othersum, AVG(ototal) AS otheravg
           FROM other_app2
           GROUP BY oaic) AS other
  ON other.oaic = t1.id;
```

--
If this gives the results your were hoping for, I would replace the **t1** derived table in the `FROM` clause with the table whose primary key I described above AND probably has those columns (e.g., region, town, etc) that I did not include